# Bidagent link unsecured causing SSL to fail

Tags: wordpress, ssl

So I got an ssl certificate for my site and it shows secure on every page but my main home page.  It is a word press site and when I run a Why No Padlock report it comes up with the following...

A file with an insecure url of "http://bidagent.xad.com/conv/143926?ts=%pord=!?" was loaded on line: 1 of https://******.com/.
Errors that are reported on line 1 are generally not part of the source code. This error may be caused by an external javascript file which is writing to the page, however we are unable to reliably detect these scripts in our automated test.
Please contact us using the "Need Help?" link below if you need assistance with resolving this error.

I have searched every file on my site for *bidagent* and it is not found, but when I view source on the main page there it is in an  tag at the bottom of the home page.   Any ideas how to get rid of this nuisance?

Answer (score 1):

The script is not coming from WP, it has to be a plugin or theme.

1. did you try disabling all plugins and theme, check if problem script is gone, then re-activate all plugins one by one?
2. The url can come from the database, did you also search the DB?
3. The domain http://bidagent.xad.com doesn't look good, if a plugin is not causing this, 'other people' may have (had) access to your site.
4. Note: Malicious scripts are almost always scrambled, so you will never find something with a file search.

Regards, Bjorn

Comment: I disabled all plug-ins as you suggested and the main home page still will not display the secure symbol.  The theme was custom built for my employer by a web-design firm, so I'm fairly confident it is not theme related.  I also did do a search of all the databases and could not find anything there that would be driving this issue.  When I pull up the page that is the culprit it is clear that it simply is a little black line banner (just an img file) at the bottom of the screen, but I can't for the life of me determine how it gets there or why it is causing a mixed content warning.

Comment: The mixced warning is because something is loaded from a NON-ssl source, this will trigger the warning. Can you share a link to the problem page? Also, we have to rule out everything, so please also try to switch the theme to a WP default one.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar issue on a site of mine. Tracing it back it allegedly comes from gtm.js - which makes it look like it's from Google. I ended up removing the code we had for google tag manager, getting a fresh copy and then replacing the removed code. Problem gone.

Comment: Upon further review, the advertising agency associated with the site I maintain uses a third party service and they provide the gtm and they link in xad.com. It's definitely a localize/geo advertising platform which appears to now be called GroundTruth. Their updated code secures the process.